# Gzip ASP.NET in debug mode

Tags: asp.net, debugging, gzip, localhost

I've tried to setup compression (both dynamic and static) in IIS7 for my local system, but when start my ASP.NET site using the debugger, YSlow tells me that all of the files (aspx, js, css, etc.) are not compressed. Any ideas? I really want to test this before I make changes to the production server.

Comment: Do you wnat gzipping contents in application side global.asax will help you

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Cassini as your server? If so it does not support compression that I know of.

You might try using Fiddler to see what the accept headers are that are being sent back and forth:

- [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)
- [Enable compression on dynamic content in IIS7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753681%28WS.10%29.aspx)
- [Problem with GZIP transfer using webrequest](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/233058-httpwebrequest-get-no-gzip)

Comment: I'm not using Cassini; I'm using IIS7.

Comment: Ok. Well fiddler might indicate if the server is not sending the compression allowed header.